# Action leaves the mic open

Tags: actions-on-google

> Your Action either leaves the mic open for a user command without a prompt such as a greeting, or an implicit or explicit question.

how can you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution while you're getting started is to ask "anything else I can help you with?" after any interaction that doesn't have a question and create a 'no' intent which will exit the app

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this response from the review team is a design problem, not a coding problem.

It means that you have said something, but not prompted the user to reply to you. So the user does not know what to do next.

For example, if we had this conversation:

```
Action: What is your favorite color?
User:   Blue
Action: Great, I'll remember that it is blue.
```

and then nothing happening, the review team would flag it for keeping the microphone open without making it clear what the user should do next.

We can change this to something like:

```
Action: What is your favorite color?
User:   Blue
Action: Great, I'll remember that it is blue. What would you like to do next?
```

and it will pass review.

If you actually want to end your conversation instead of asking the user something else, make sure you close the conversation. If your conversation isn't closing when it should be, then update your question to include the code that doesn't seem to be working.